# How to freeze an im2txt model?

Tags: tensorflow

I fine-tuned im2txt model and obtained the ckpt.data, ckpt.index and ckpt.meta files and a graph.pbtxt file using the procedure in the im2txt github.
The model seems to work well as it produces almost correct captions.

Now I would like to freeze this model to use it on android.

I used the freeze_graph.py script in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py.

```
python freeze_graph.py --input_graph=/path/to/graph.pbtxt --input_binary=false --input_checkpoint=/path/to/model.ckpt --output_graph=/path/to/output_graph.pb --output_node_names="softmax,lstm/initial_state,lstm/state"
```

And I have the following error : `AssertionError: softmax is not in graph`.

The discussion in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/816 is about the same problem but it did not help me very much.
Indeed, when I look in the graph.pbtxt generated after fine-tuning, I cannot find softmax, lstm/initial_state and lstm/state.
But in the show_and_tell_model.py file of im2txt, the names of the tensors seem to be "softmax", "lstm/initial_state" and "lstm/state". So, I don't know what's happening.

I hope I was clear enough about what I've tried so far. Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
Stephane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found and verified the answer: in inference_wrapper.base.py, just add something like `saver.save(sess, "model/ckpt4")` after `saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)` in `def _restore_fn(sess):`. Then rebuild and run_inference and you'll get a model that can be frozen, transformed, and optionally memmapped, to be loaded by iOS and Android apps.

For detailed commands to freeze, transform, and convert to memmapped, see my answer at [Error using Model after using optimize_for_inference.py on frozen graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212068/error-using-model-after-using-optimize-for-inference-py-on-frozen-graph/48638586#48638586).

Comment: Hi,
Sorry it was not clear enough in my answer. Glad you found how to freeze the model.

I am still unable to use my model on Android. I used the commands from your answer and I have the following error when loading the model with TensorflowInferenceInterface :
"Not a valid TensorFlow Graph serialization: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 5 for 'ResizeBilinear' (op: 'ResizeBilinear') with input shapes: [1,1,299,299,3], [2]."
Would you have an idea about what is wrong?
Regards,
Stephane

Comment: Did you use the transformed file generated with:
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \
--in_graph=/tmp/ckpt4_frozen.pb \
--out_graph=/tmp/ckpt4_frozen_transformed.pb \
--inputs="convert_image/Cast,input_feed,lstm/state_feed" \
--outputs="softmax,lstm/initial_state,lstm/state" \
--transforms='
      strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="1,299,299,3")
      fold_constants(ignore_errors=true) 
      fold_batch_norms
      fold_old_batch_norms'

Comment: Yes, I used this one. Maybe it's a problem with my frozen model I use before transforming it? In the Java code, I tried "input_feed" and "convert_image/Cast" as input nodes but none of them is working.

Is there a specific version of tensorflow to use (>1.4 for instance)? Still trying to make it work.
Anyway, thanks for taking time to answer and trying to help !

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

I think I finally got the solution. In case it is useful for others, here it is:

After training, you obtain ckpt.data, ckpt.index and ckpt.meta files and a graph.pbtxt file.

You then have to load this model in 'inference' mode (see InferenceWrapper in im2txt). It builds a graph with the correct names 'softmax', 'lstm/initial_state' and 'lstm/state'. You save this graph (with the same ckpt format) and then you can apply the freeze_graph script to obtain the frozen model.

Regards,
Stephane

Comment: I added 
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, "/tmp/im2txt.ckpt")
in inference_step and build_model of inference_wrapper.py, as well as in _restore_fn of inference_wrapper_base.py. Then I used the generated checkpoint file in python tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py  --input_graph=graph.pbtxt --input_checkpoint=/tmp/im2txt.ckpt --output_graph=/tmp/im2txt_frozen_graph.pb --output_node_names="softmax,lstm/initial_state,lstm/state" but always get the error AssertionError: softmax is not in graph. Can you post the exact place, file and code you used to fix the problem? Thanks!