# Error using Model after using optimize_for_inference.py on frozen graph

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow, tensorboard

I was using `tensorflows script` `optimize_for_inderence.py` on the `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco model` with following command:

```
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.optimize_for_inference \
    --input /path/to/frozen_inference_graph.pb \
    --output /path/to/optimized_inference_graph.pb \
    --input_names=image_tensor \
    --output_names=detection_boxes,detection_scores,num_detections,detection_classes
```

It worked without errors, but if i want to use the created `Model .pb` file for `Tensorboard` or for `Inference` it gives me following error:

> ValueError: graph_def is invalid at node u'ToFloat': Input tensor 'image_tensor:0' Cannot convert a tensor of type float32 to an input of type uint8.

See the original graph visualized by Tensorbaord:

[image]

As you can see the node `ToFloat` comes directly after the `image_tensor` input

So something apparently went wrong with the optimization. But what?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: Did you solve it? Can you post the code here?

Answer (score 5):

I saw a similar error "Input 0 of node ExpandDims_6 was passed float from input_feed:0 incompatible with expected int64" when loading the model file generated by the optimize_for_inference tool.

Pete's comment "the new graph transform approach to removing unused nodes might be more robust?
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/#optimizing-for-deployment" on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8242 seems to suggest we should use the new transform_graph tool.

That there's no mention of the optimize_for_inference tool in the updated TensorFlow Mobile documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile also suggests the transform_graph tool.

Just when I doubted the culprit is in the optimization tool I saw your question. Thanks for that.. Just tried the transform_graph tool, it worked, both with the transformed model and further memmapped model after transformation. Below is the 3 commands freeze-transform-memmapped I used:

```
python tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py  \
--input_meta_graph=/tmp/ckpt4.meta \
--input_checkpoint=/tmp/ckpt4 \
--output_graph=/tmp/ckpt4_frozen.pb \
--output_node_names="softmax,lstm/initial_state,lstm/state" \
--input_binary=true

bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \
--in_graph=/tmp/ckpt4_frozen.pb \
--out_graph=/tmp/ckpt4_frozen_transformed.pb \
--inputs="convert_image/Cast,input_feed,lstm/state_feed" \
--outputs="softmax,lstm/initial_state,lstm/state" \
--transforms='
      strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="1,299,299,3")
      fold_constants(ignore_errors=true) 
      fold_batch_norms
      fold_old_batch_norms'  


bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/util/convert_graphdef_memmapped_format \
--in_graph=/tmp/ckpt4_frozen_transformed.pb \
--out_graph=/tmp/ckpt4_frozen_transformed_memmapped.pb
```

Comment: Would be nice if you share your experience after you have used the tool

Comment: nice bro! 
But from which model are your checkpoints you use in the first place?
Did you do it with ssd_mobilenet?

Comment: This is for im2txt (image captioning) model. I'm actually writing a book on building mobile apps with TensorFlow and did the ssd_mobilenet in Ch 3 but I just used the frozen model there. The early access program of the book just started a few days ago and you may want to give it a free trial: https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/intelligent-mobile-projects-tensorflow

Comment: nice work!
would you mind trying the optimization on ssd mobilenet?

Comment: Sure but probably this weekend. I'm already late finishing the current chapter due to the problem above. Will let you know in a few days how it looks.

Comment: @JeffTang Please help me. I have posted a few questions found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361275/how-to-use-transform-graph-in-tensorflow, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52380058/error-in-using-strip-unused-nodes-in-transform-graph-in-tensorflow

Comment: @JeffTang What is `ckpt4.meta` in `input_meta_graph`? And where do I find the `ckpt4` for the `input_checkpoint`? Upon checking the generated files after training they are: `model.ckpt-68450.meta`, `model.ckpt-68505.data-00000-of-00001`,  `model.ckpt-68505.index`, `graph.pbtxt`, `checkpoint`. Which is which?

Comment: @JeffTang And are the output nodes he specified in this question correct?

Comment: @JeffTang This is my command and it didn't work `python /Users/cvsanbuenaventura/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py --input_meta_graph=/Userstsearch/object_ding/model.ckpt-68449.meta --input_checkpoint=/Users/cvsanbuenaventura/Documents/tensorflow_fastlog/models/research/object_detection/training/model.ckpt-68449 --output_graph=/Users/cvsanbuenaventura/Documents/tensorflow_fastlog/models/research/object_detection/inference_graph/frozen_inference_graph-python.pb --output_node_names="detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections" --input_binary=true`